# How to get the email templates usage in vf page

Tags: apex, email-template

I have a page in which I display the no of times the email templates was used in the particular days. But it is displaying the total no of times used instead of the particular usage. Here is my SOQL.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Subject,Folder.Name,LastUsedDate, TimesUsed FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Folder.Name='Customer Service Technology' AND IsActive = true AND LastUsedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:10
```

If the above is wrong , please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

The `TimesUsed` field returns the total number of times the template has been used. Filtering by the `LastUsedDate` will return the total number of times any template which has been sent in the last 10 days has been sent, not the number of times a given template was sent in the last 10 days.

For email history, you're better off querying the `EmailMessage` table.. which after reading the docs for I now realize does not include the template id, which basically makes the table worthless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if TimesUsed is a custom field or how it's populated, but it would seem that you'd want to use an AggregateResult query with `Count()`. See the [SOQL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) for more on this.

`LastUsedDate=Last_N_Days:10` makes no sense and can't be used in this context. It seems that what you want is either the `count()` over the "Last N Days" or to use `LastUsedDate >= LastUsedDate.AddDays(-N)`.

If `TimesUsed` is a custom field, depending on how it's populated, you could possibly do the following:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Subject,Folder.Name,LastUsedDate, TimesUsed FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Folder.Name='Customer Service Technology' AND IsActive = true AND LastUsedDate >= LastUsedDate.addDays(-10)
```

At a minimum, it should at least return results for you and you could subtract the last value in the list from the first value (or min and max of TimesUsed during that period).

Comment: TimesUsed is a standard field. And also can you please tell the difference in the two queries. addays(-10) and last:n:days=10 gives same results anyway

Comment: `LastUsedDate = LastNDays `specifies that the `LastUsedDate` is `Today()`. You're in essence saying it must be within the last 10 days. The other takes the Actual `LastUsedDate` and subtracts 10 days to get the date and probably should be used as `LastUsedDate >= LastUsedDate.addDays(-10)` if you want it for the 10 previous days from when it was actually last used.